# Issue when deleting rows from my database using html, php, js

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm making an app in which I have this table:

```
<?php
require_once 'Connect2db3.php';
?>    
<form>    
<fieldset>
<article class="rondehoeken"> 
<header>
    <div class="streep1"></div>
    <div class="streep2"></div>
    <div class="streep3"></div>
    <div class="streep4"></div>
    <div class="streep5"></div>
    <h1 id="artikel-titel" >Op Vooraad</h1>
</header>

<div id="artikel-container">    
<table class="table 1">
<thead>
 <title>Inventory Grid.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <style type = "text/css">
    table, td, th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    } 
    </style>
</thead>    
<tbody>
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","inventarisdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM BCD");

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Categorie</th>
<th>SerieNummer</th>
<th>MacAdress</th>
<th>ProductCode</th>
<th>Prijs</th>
<th>RekNummer</th>
<th>PaletNummer</th>
<th>Hoeveelheid</th>
<th>Aantekeningen</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Categorie'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SerieNummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['MacAdress'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ProductCode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Prijs'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['RekNummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['PaletNummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hoeveelheid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Aantekeningen'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><input type="hidden" class="entryid" name="id" value='.$row['ID'].' /><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</article>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

In the header:

Delete form:

```
<?php
$db = array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => 'admin',
    'dbname' => 'inventarisdb'
);

if(!mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']))
{
    trigger_error('Fout bij verbinden: '.mysql_error());
}
elseif(!mysql_select_db($db['dbname']))
{
    trigger_error('Fout bij selecteren database: '.mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $sql = "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'";
    if(!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        trigger_error('MySQL in ANSI niet mogelijk');
    }
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id='$Categorie', '$SerieNummer', '$MacAdress', '$ProductCode', '$Prijs', '$RekNummer','$PaletNummer' ,'$Hoeveelheid', '$Aantekeningen'";
?>
```

This table looks up data from another table and also provides the option to delete a row in that table from the database.

Everything I just said this table does works with this script, except for the data being actually deleted from my Database. Upon pressing delete the delete action gets executed with a prompt an all saying that ur about to delete a row. It removes it from the table but when u check in the database or simply refresh the page with the table, That row is still there and hasn't been deleted

Any ideas why this is happening or what to do ? Or maybe how to do it easier ?

Comment: it's better to move your title tag inside the head tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what your sample code demonstrates, I came to the same conclusion as @BabakBandpay; **you never actually run the DELETE query**.

Regardless of whether that is true or not, while it's a good step to move to the MySQLi library, you're still using code that is **very** susceptible to SQL injection. Try using a prepared statement instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Here's an example based off of your code (and the API documentation):

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'inventarisdb');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // ... the rest of your code

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    $success = $stmt->execute();

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

This code, while untested and not really production-quality, is quite a bit safer just by the nature of bound statements:

> Bound variables will be escaped automatically by the server.

I was more of a fan of PDO when I still coded in PHP, but using the OOP verion of MySQLi is a decent compromise, so I'd highly recommend reading through the examples in the documentation.

**EDIT:** As an addendum, I'd also recommend running your input variable(s) through the filter module (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php). Assuming `$id` should be an integer, I'd update the assignment to:

```
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

This will remove everything from `$_GET['id']` that isn't a digit or a +/- sign.

Comment: Thank you! I will read this through and try it out! Much oblidged!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this will work

```
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id='$Categorie', '$SerieNummer', '$MacAdress', '$ProductCode', '$Prijs', '$RekNummer','$PaletNummer' ,'$Hoeveelheid', '$Aantekeningen'";
```

You should separate the parameters with **AND** or OR, depending on what your successful delete criteria needs not a comma, **also provide the column name each** time.

Something like

```
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id='$Categorie' AND  serial_number='$SerieNummer', //etc
```

**It would be better to delete based on a primary key rather than such a range of values**

Also do not use mysql_ functions, use mysqli or PDO with parameterised queries

Comment: I changed it all to AND which I should use rather than OR in this case, but I get the exact same executed actions and results.

Comment: @Kentje, This is not going to work for you because non of those variables that you've used are defined.

Comment: provide the column name for each of the ANDs/ORs

Comment: @ vinodadhikary, What do u mean by this? All the variables I used are fields in my tables in my DB.. how could they not be defined? or what do u mean? 
And how do u suggest I make it work?

Comment: @Kentje, I am talking about the variables like $Categorie, $SerieNummer etc.

Comment: @Kentje The format of a WHERE clause with multiple parameters needs to be WHERE column_name = Value AND column_name=value etc

Comment: But allen213 isn't this what I did by changing the comma's to AND? :P
or do u mean theres a parameter missing?

Comment: No you need to specify the name of the column again after each AND. Post your new query as a comment and we can check syntax

Comment: $id = $_GET['id'];
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id='$Categorie' AND SerieNummer='$SerieNummer' AND Macadress='$MacAdress' AND Productcode='$ProductCode' AND Prijs='$Prijs' AND RekNummer='$RekNummer' AND PaletNummer='$PaletNummer' AND Hoeveelheid='$Hoeveelheid' AND Aantekeningen='$Aantekeningen'";
?>

Comment: Nothing technically wrong with that query providing your column names match and variables are set. It is much better to delete base on a single id. If the id field is unique then all the other parameters are unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

as it is obvious in your code, you don't execute the query.

Comment: This is true unless he forgot to paste that bit - the query in the original would not work though

Answer (score 1):

Your hidden input is named `id` and you are calling `$id = $_GET['id']`, all other variables you have in your query are undefined because you haven't shown where you've defined them if you have defined them.

Replace:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id='$Categorie', '$SerieNummer', '$MacAdress', '$ProductCode', '$Prijs', '$RekNummer','$PaletNummer' ,'$Hoeveelheid', '$Aantekeningen'";
```

with:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']); // assuming your id column is integer type.
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id=$id";
```

Also note that `mysql_` functions are deprecated.  You should be using either `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: U mean '$ID'"; then right? And it didn't make a difference after I just tried, I get the same executed action but still it doesn't delete the stats from my DB.

Comment: No `$id` from `<input type="hidden" class="entryid" name="id" value='.$row['ID'].' />`

Comment: When I do this I get an error in my script saying that id = undefined variable and my table no longer displays the data it looks up

Comment: @Kentje, There was a missing closing double quotes `"` in my query.  Please try that again.

Comment: My input class = entryid, name = id and value = $row,
All my variables are defined as $ row(s) so how can this not work, I don't think the probleml lies here, tho i much appreciate ur help and advice! but after making the chages u suggested I get either the same results or an error which doens't let me see my table :S

Comment: yes I added them I noticed u missed them from the beginning :) still no change

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($_GET)` before you execute the query in your delete page.

Comment: Ehh.. wut? how to post this ? Not familiar with this

Comment: Just before the `$id = $_GET['id'];`, type `var_dump($_GET); die;` and when you go to this page you'll see the output in your browser.  Paste that content here.

Comment: I'm upvoting this as it's much better to delete based on a single field

Comment: I am not seeing any output in my browser, as a matter of fact I don't see the var_dump($_GET); die; get added to the script in Notepad++.. (its like the code is faulty or I am putting it wrong, Don't know this code)

Comment: Checking it out now! 
also checking W3schools for possible different easier ways to reach the same result.
Tried using fiddler to see what happens, Fiddler shows me as i press delete that it goes to /serverfolder/delete.php?id=1
So I am thinking there is just one little flaw somewhere in my code leaving  me stuck on this.
And to avoid Huge comment pages on this topic I am going to look for alternative options!
I will let u know what i find!

Comment: Thank you all very much for your quick replies and attention!
Cheers!